# Expo dev tool: Running Dev app in the background

Tags: android, react-native, expo

This my first time developing in Expo, I'm building app that trace the location and send the data to server every 5 sec using node. I'm using [TaskManager](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/task-manager) API from expo I'd follow everything and it works I'm getting the data. But when I put my app in the background it stops the `console.log(data)`.

Is this should be running (the `TaskManager`) in background task even in Dev environment using **Expo Dev Tool** or is it needed to put to production mode bofore it works?

When I turn the app into background mode like this, my `console.log` stop working.

[image]

My sample Code App.js

```
const LOCATION_TRACKER = 'background-task-location';

export default class App extends Component {
     state = {
      mapRegion: null,
      hasLocationPermissions: false,
      locationResult: null,
      marker: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0
      },
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0,
      location: null,
      errorMessage: null
    }


   componentDidMount() {
    //this.watchCurLocation();
    this.onLoad();  

   }

   //init task manager
  onLoad = async() => {
    let isRegistered = await TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync(LOCATION_TRACKER)
    if (!isRegistered) await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TRACKER, {
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
      /* after edit */
      timeInterval: 2500,
      distanceInterval: 5,
    })
  }


onPress = async () => {
    console.log('waiting')
    await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TRACKER, {
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
      timeInterval: 5000,
      distanceInterval: 5

    });

    console.log('waiting for get task option');
    //const data = await TaskManager.getTaskOptionsAsync(LOCATION_TRACKER)
    //console.log(data);

  };


watchCurLocation = () =>{
    this.onPress();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.watchCurLocation();
    }, 5000);
  }


}


TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TRACKER, ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
    // Error occurred - check `error.message` for more details.
    return;
  }
  if (data) {
    const { locations } = data;
    console.log(data)
    // do something with the locations captured in the background
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

From Android Oreo and up the application will not run such tasks when in background.
due restrictions : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services

You have to show some notification in the system tray in order to get the tracker work in the background.

a) you can try to add a notification that uses a channel, without need to eject expo

https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/guides/notification-channels

or b) eject expo and add a foregroundservice that will start when the application is going to background

similar to this, just to get the idea:

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {
///....

   public  void toForeground(){ 
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification()); 
    }

   public void toBackground(){ 
        stopForeground(true); 
   }   
    /**
     * Returns the {@link NotificationCompat} used as part of the foreground service.
     */
    private Notification getNotification() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);  

        // The PendingIntent that leads to a call to onStartCommand() in this service.
        PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // The PendingIntent to launch activity.
        PendingIntent activityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .addAction(R.drawable.shell_notification_icon, getString(R.string.launch_activity),
                        activityPendingIntent) 
                .setContentText(text)
                .setContentTitle(Utils.getLocationTitle(this))
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.shell_notification_icon)
                .setTicker(text)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Set the Channel ID for Android O.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID); // Channel ID
        }

        return builder.build();
    }
//...
}
```